# Machine Learning Server (SQL): how to backup and restore Python and Packages

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, backup, microsoft-machine-learning-server

After installation of numpy-1.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl package in Python 3.5 ( SQL Server Machine Learning Services for windows x64, SQL Management Studio v17.9.1, MSSQL Server 2017) I recieved the error:

```
Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script. Please check the requirements of 'Python' runtime.
```

If will not be able to fix the problem, I would prefer not to reinstall ML Server from scratch, but restore Python and its packages from backup.

Is there a method of backup and restore Python and Packages?
May be, it is sufficient to backup and restore some Python folders like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Python backup/recovery steps on ML Sevrer:
Backup - copy somewhere the folder

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\

with workable Python version

Recovery:

1) stop SQL server including Launchpad

2) drop\replace current Python folder

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\

3) copy PYTHON_SERVICES folder with workable Python version into

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\

4) start SQL server

5) start Launchpad